# When does python copy local lists added to a global dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
g_list = {}

def add_new_row(row_key, curr_value):
    global g_list

    curr_row = [None] * 2  # a local variable. I expected it to disappear after the function returns.
    curr_row[0] = curr_value
    curr_row[1] = curr_value * 2

    if row_key not in g_list:
        g_list[row_key] = []
    g_list[row_key].append(curr_row)
    curr_row[1] = 100  # just for test and illustrate the append by reference.

def main():
    curr_v = 1
    add_new_row(1, curr_v)

    curr_v = 2
    add_new_row(2, curr_v)

    global g_list
    print(g_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
{1: [[1, 100]], 2: [[2, 100]]}
```

Based on my understanding, the append operation in `g_list[row_key].append` is copy-by-reference and that is why the value of `curr_row[1]` is always `100`. However, I don't understand how the global variable `g_list` could contain the value of a local allocated list (i.e. `curr_row`) even after the function is returned.

I expected to use the following line:

```
g_list[row_key].append(curr_row[:])
```

but the following code works:

```
g_list[row_key].append(curr_row)
```

Can someone give me some advice when this deep-copy of a local list happened?

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing *objects* with *names*. **All** Python objects live on the heap, and names are just *references* to those objects. The list is never copied, Python doesn't have to.

You can think of names as labels on a piece of string, and you are tying those labels to objects. You can use as many labels as you like to reference a given object. Local names in a function are just more labels, and it is the **labels** that are cleaned up when the function exits. Objects, on the other hand will continue to exist until there are no more labels attached to them.

For the purpose of this analogy, the indices of a list just more labels, and keys in a dictionary act as labels for the corresponding values. In fact, the globals of a module are really just key-value pairs in a dictionary!

So in your specific example, you created a list object that references `None`, twice:

```
[None] * 2
```

At this point, this list has no labels attached, it has only just been created. The only reason that it doesn't go up in smoke immediately is that the Python execution stack is referencing it. The next instruction that Python then executes is to take the top of the execution stack and assign it to a local because the rest of that statement is:

```
curr_row = ...
```

So the list object above now has a label attached to it, the local `curr_now`.

You then create a few more values and attach those to indices in the list:

```
curr_row[0] = curr_value
curr_row[1] = curr_value * 2
```

So given a `curr_value` of `1` you now have this:

```
+---------+          +---------+              +---------+  
| Globals |    |     |  Heap   |        |     | Locals  |  
+---------+    |     +---------+        |     +---------+  
               |                        |                  
               |                        |                  
 g_list ------------> {}                |                  
               |                        |                  
               |            [1, 2] <----------- curr_row   
               |                        |
```

(The above diagram simplifies the situation somewhat, as the integers `1` and `2` are really separate objects too, but that'd make the above diagram unreadable).

Next, you add a key to `g_list` with a new, empty list: `row_key` is `1` here:

```
if row_key not in g_list:
    g_list[row_key] = curr_row
```

This creates a reference between the dictionary and a new, empty list object:

```
+---------+          +---------+              +---------+
| Globals |    |     |  Heap   |       |      | Locals  |
+---------+    |     +---------+       |      +---------+
               |                       |                 
               |                       |                 
 g_list -------------> {1: <value>}    |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             v         |                 
               |            []         |                 
               |                       |                 
               |                       |                 
               |                       |                 
               |          [1, 2] <------------- curr_row 
               |                       |
```

Finally, you alter that empty list by adding a new index to it, because you append the list referenced by `curr_row` to it:

```
g_list[row_key].append(curr_row)
```

which changes the situation to:

```
+---------+          +---------+              +---------+
| Globals |    |     |  Heap   |       |      | Locals  |
+---------+    |     +---------+       |      +---------+
               |                       |                 
               |                       |                 
 g_list -------------> {1: <value>}    |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             v         |                 
               |           [<0>]       |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             v         |                 
               |          [1, 2] <------------- curr_row 
               |                       |                 
               |                       |
```

Note how the dictionary value references the list, which in turn references the list with `1` and `2` in it. The next line alters the latter list by assigning to index 1:

```
curr_row[1] = 100
```

altering the situation to:

```
+---------+          +---------+              +---------+
| Globals |    |     |  Heap   |       |      | Locals  |
+---------+    |     +---------+       |      +---------+
               |                       |                 
               |                       |                 
 g_list -------------> {1: <value>}    |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             v         |                 
               |           [<0>]       |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             |         |                 
               |             v         |                 
               |         [1, 100]<------------- curr_row 
               |                       |                 
               |                       |
```

Finally, the function exits, removing all local names:

```
+---------+          +---------+    
| Globals |    |     |  Heap   |    
+---------+    |     +---------+    
               |                    
               |                    
 g_list -------------> {1: <value>} 
               |             |      
               |             |      
               |             v      
               |           [<0>]    
               |             |      
               |             |      
               |             v      
               |         [1, 100]   
               |                    
               |
```

The list you created inside the function and referenced as `curr_row` **is not removed** because there is still a reference to it, from index `0` of the list that the `g_list` dictionary is referencing as a value.

**Nowhere does Python have to make a copy of the list (deep or otherwise)**.

As a side note: You don't need to use the `global g_list` statements in your functions. That statement is only ever needed if you wanted to alter what a global name (label) is connected to. You only set `g_list` **once**, tying that label to a dictionary object. From there on out that label remains connected to the same dictionary. You only need to use `global <name>` if you need to re-bind such a name from within a function, and only because *otherwise* Python treats names you assign to as locals. Because no attempts are made in your functions to change what `g_list` is referencing, you can safely remove the `global g_list` statements from your code without altering how the code behaves.

Comment: This post answered my OP and showed me the real usage of the `global variable` within a function. Thank you!

Comment: @q0987: Glad you found it helpful! Anything missing still? Can I be *really* greedy and ask if you are considering awarding an 'accept' too? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have scoped allocation of memory, but rather scoped references.

Python manages the deletion of objects that are no longer being used by a system of reference counting. For every object, the interpreter tracks the number of references to that object. References can be names used in your code, or pointers stored in data structures:

```
a = object()  # 1 reference
b = [a]       # 2 references
a = 1         # Still one reference in the list
b = None      # No more references, so the garbage collector will destroy the object
```

When the number of references to an object reaches zero, the interpreter knows that the object is no longer being used, and it can be garbage collected. (The actual implementation is a little more sophisticated, to deal with things like cyclical references).

So it's not unusual for objects to persist outside of the scope that created them.  (The Python language/interpreter doesn't enforce concepts of object ownership).  The below function creates 3 objects and doesn't destroy or copy any of them, even though only one is explicitly returned to the caller:

```
def f():
    return [[], []]
```

So, to address your question directly:

> However, I don't understand how the global variable `g_list` could
>   contain the value of a local allocated list (i.e. `curr_row`) even after
>   the function is returned.

Python does not have locally allocated lists, only local references to lists. No deep copy is performed, because there's no expectation that the function scope ending frees any memory it allocated.

Comment: "The actual implementation is a little more sophisticated, to deal with things like cyclical references" -- isn't the reference cycles handled by `gc` and is optional?

Answer (score -1):

#### If you want to deepcopy

You might be interested in the `copy` module. Like this:

```py
from copy import deepcopy
list_b = deepcopy(list_a)
```

And you'll have different references. Anything else in python is shallow copies.

(well, unless you re-implement some deepcopying yourself... but that's not gonna happen by accident.)

#### list.extend

> I expected to use the following line:
>
> `g_list[row_key].append(curr_row[:])`
>
> but the following code works:
>
> `g_list[row_key].append(curr_row)`
>
> Can someone give me some advice when this deep-copy of a local list happened?

the `list.append()` method appends a single item to a list. `list.extend()` instead expects an iterable (such as a list, or a [:] slice of one), and appends all items in that iterable to the list.

#### So what DID happen?

> However, I don't understand how the global variable g_list could contain the value of a local allocated list (i.e. curr_row) even after the function is returned.

1. There's 2 references for it - one local to the function, and one inside the other (global) list.
2. Then the function ends, and the reference inside the global list is still alive.
3. The reference local to the function is deleted
4. But it's still alive in the other list, so the list is never deleted.

While perhaps not technically true, you could say Python doesn't create references, it performs name bindings. Therefore, in these operations, the following happens:

```py
a = "something"                       # Binds name "a" to string "something"
identity_of_a = id(a)                 # Binds name "identity_of_a" to the result of function id(a)
b = a                                 # Binds name "b" to string "something"
a = "something completely different"  # Binds name "a" to string "something completely different"
print(id(b) == identity_of_a)         # Compares the result of id(b) to the value bound to "identity_of_a", and prints the result.
```

Will ALWAYS print True. And do note that at no point after initial assignment did anything happen to the string "something", except for updating of it's refcounting value.

Comment: No copies of the list were made, anywhere, deep or shallow. And Python does make references, Python uses references throughout. I’m not sure why you are confusing matters more by saying that name bindings are something other than references.

Comment: If you have a reference, you can dereference it to get the value of the object. That's not a concept with Python names. I'll fix the bit about copying, you're right.

Comment: You can, in a way, dereference. Given a string with a name and a namespace, you can resolve that to the object. Via `getattr()` or `globals()` or `locals()`.

Comment: Can't do that to a name, though.